# Need to remove password restrictions

Tags: lock-screens, password

I put in my current password and it says that I can't have password

My lock screen settings say I can't have password. It says an administrator denied it or something like that

.[image: .]

Comment: Is your device under a MDM platform? Or is your device encrypted by an app that is set as administrator? This would stop you making the changes.

Comment: Some account or app with administrator privileges is preventing it from occuring. This is common if you have your work email on your phone and a group policy is being applied to your account. Go to Settings - Security - Device Administrators and find the offending app or account and remove it from the device, that is the only way to remove the security requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It means, You enabled high protection by using any third party application.

That app precenting you from setting No pass or Swipe to lock and force you to choose a protection. That is **either pin or pattern or password**.

This is for your good.

Go to Settings -> Security -> Device administrators. You can see a list there.

Disable all apps other than **Device manager and your phone manufacturers Application**.

Then there is no issues in removing the lock

Answer (score 0):

You may try also to long press power button and enter phone into safemode in order for third party apps not to work. Then you may go to app manager and uninstall or dissable the application that causes the problem.